# Can an output public key appear more than once in the blockchain

Tags: blockchain, block-explorer

The output public key `9b2e4c0281c0b02e7c53291a94d1d0cbff8883f8024f5142ee494ffbbd088071` appears in the the following blocks:

https://moneroblocks.info/search/000e412e54c9ef87f175c3645ca82a3046b125f6e032019b353df343f123d703
https://moneroblocks.info/search/0006a06fc3e6f4927e4e4a51d592887ebdf31c10fda5c0966356b2fb09131544
https://xmrchain.net/tx/c88ce9783b4f11190d7b9c17a69c1c52200f9faaee8e98dd07e6811175177139

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Yes. It can appear in multiple blocks / transactions. It being an input/output doesn't make it the real one vs a decoy though.

Comment: Wont that mean double spending? There was a similar discussion on reddit where it was said that you cant have duplicate vout:keys as that would result in a double spending situation

Comment: Nope. Key images help protect against a double-spend.